# Using cut as part of a function in R to calculate quintiles

Tags: r, function, quantile

I've been asked to use "cut" in R to create quartiles for my variable wt71 in database nhefs. Here is my code:

```
 apply_quintiles <-function(x) {
cut(x, breaks =c(quantile(nhefs$wt71,probs=seq(0,1, by=0.25))), labels=c(25, 50, 75, 100),include.lowest=TRUE)
}
nhefs$quintiles<-sapply(nhefs$wt71,apply_quintiles)
head(mean_weights)
table(nhefs$quintiles)
```

Here is my output:
[image]

This is very far from what I was expecting:

[image]
Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Can you provide the output you were expecting, either as an R object or text table (not image), and a reproducible example of input data (paste output of `dput(input_data)`)? See [/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Note that you are calculating quartiles. To do quintiles you would need `probs=seq(0,1, by=0.2)`. (Your language is inconsistent, so it's not clear what you actually want...)

Answer (score 0):

The `table` created shows the number (N) of rows that fall within that quartile. That is different than the `wt71` values computed by `summary` indicating threshold for 1st or 3rd quartile or median. (Note: as @Gregor pointed out, these are quartiles not quintiles.)

To illustrate, I changed the labels to clarify the quartiles produced:

```
set.seed(1)

nhefs <- data.frame(
  wt71 =  round(runif(100, min=1, max=100), 0)
)

apply_quintiles <-function(x) {
  cut(x, breaks =c(quantile(nhefs$wt71,probs=seq(0,1, by=0.25))), labels=c("0-25", "25-50", "50-75", "75-100"),include.lowest=TRUE)
}

nhefs$quintiles<-sapply(nhefs$wt71,apply_quintiles)

table(nhefs$quintiles)

  0-25  25-50  50-75 75-100 
    25     25     26     24
```

This demonstrates equal distribution of the 100 random numbers across the 4 quartiles. There are N=25 between 0-25%ile and N=26 at 50-75%ile, etc. These numbers are not values of `wt71` but instead of the number of data elements or rows that fall in that range of percentiles.

Here's the `summary` of `wt71`:

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
2.00   32.75   49.50   52.24   77.00   99.00
```

These values correspond to thresholds for 1st quartile, median, and 3rd quartile. These threshold values do relate to value of `wt71`. For example, a `wt71` value of 30 would be less than 1st quartile level.

Taking a look at `nhefs` now:

```
head(nhefs)

  wt71 quintiles
1   27      0-25
2   38     25-50
3   58     50-75
4   91    75-100
5   21      0-25
6   90    75-100
```

Notice that for your different `wt71` values, they are assigned to different quartiles. The `wt71` of 27 is in the lowest quartile (0-25) as this value is less than the threshold for 1st quartile of 32.75.

Hope this helps!